# How can I have minimal data do back and forth for an AJAX enabled GridView

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview, updatepanel, asp.net-4.0

I have a listview with 250 rows and 4 columns in my ASP.Net 4.0/C# application. The Rendered page size (from Trace) is 650,000 Bytes. The entire listview is in an update panel.

The listview facilitates view/add/edit/delete operations on the listview records.

Every POSTBACK action (i.e. edit click, delete click) causes a POSTBACK request of size 112,000 Bytes and an AJAX Response of ~650,000 Bytes.

The listview gets the data from a declarative data source (SQLDataSource) on the page. And the listview is bound on each round trip.

I want to reduce the data going back and forth in every call because on a slow connection, these AJAX calls take 2-3 minutes to complete.

What I have tried -
Removed the update panel over the entire listview and added an update panel over each:

- ItemTemplate contents
- AlternateItem Template contents
- Edit Template contents
- Insert Template contents

I was hoping that with the template in each row, it would reduce the size of the AJAX response since only the HTML for the update panel would come back. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work that way.

Any inputs on how the problem in my case can be solved?

Thanks in advance for looking this up.

Comment: Do you need to display all 250 rows? Adding paging should drastically decrease the data sent over the wire.

Comment: Paging was the obvious way out, but due to the requirements, we need to keep all 250 rows visible on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with an [UpdatePanel](http://blog.slaven.net.au/2008/05/02/the-updatepanel-is-evil/) is that you are not using real AJAX. Instead ASP.NET uses some really clever hacks to create the illusion of a partial page update. On the background, your whole page life cycle is executed. This also means that your complete [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) is send back and forth.

If you want a faster experience, you should not use UpdatePanels. Instead, use plain HTML controls (preferably not even server controls) and use JavaScript and a server side webservice (such as WebAPI or a WCF service) to respond to the client side requests.

Those requests and response will only contain some [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) data and no markup. Your data can be kept to a minimum. If for example, a user removes a row, you only have to send the Id of the row to your service and it will return success or failure.  The client will use JavaScript and maybe something like [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) to render the result. This will give you minimal overhead and a better performance.

Comment: Thanks. Yours is definitely a suggestion pointing is the right direction. Though we did not implement it this time due to time constraint, but have noted this solution for a future enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way to do this is to not use the ASP.NET user controls and instead do this cleanly using JavaScript, JSON, HTML and a server side web service/http handler

That way you don't have to send large HTML responses from the server to client.  You can also control when need to refresh and rebind your data.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the whole size issue has to do `ViewState`. The reason being that on every postback, even if it's an AJAX postback the `ViewState` travels with it on **every request**. The only thing you can do, without making any changes, is to enable compression on the IIS side. This, at least, will send the response compressed and the browser will take care of decompressing it.

The best approach is not to use `UpdatePanel` and `ScriptManagers` at all and instead make AJAX requests using jQuery (or whatever framework you prefer) by invoking a WCF Web service. This will not trigger the full page lifecycle and will not send the `ViewState` on every request.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I appreciate your insight. But in my case I have examined the viewstate and it small not really significant compared to the HTML Byte size.